# How can I consolidate hadoop logs?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I currently have a program that - among other things - produces log outputs. The problem is that the mappers all seem to want to log to wherever they are running. I want all of this log output to end up in a single file. I am using log4j to log information.

I was thinking that it might be possibble to somehow stream that data as a string from the Mapper back to the main function somehow, and log it that way. Is something like this possibble? Is there a better way to consolidate logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I ended up solving this problem by using MultipleOutputs. I set up one stream for the actual output, and one for the log results my code produced. This allowed me to manually log things by sending output through the log output stream. I then had a script consolidate the log files into a single file. While the automatically generated logs stayed where they originally were this solution has allowed me to send the log messsages I put into my code into a single location.

example log statement using MultipleOutputs:

```
mout.write("logOutput", new Text("INFO: "), new Text("reducertest"),
                "templogging/logfile");
```

Answer (score 0):

Each map or reduce task's log is written to the local file system of the task tracker nodes on which they were executed. The log is written to a 'userlog' directory which is defined by HADOOP_LOG_DIR, with sub directory named by task attempt ID.

These logs files can be accessed through job tracker web GUI, in each task detail page, there is a link you can click to check the log content. But from the original Apache Hadoop version, to my best knowledge, there is not any tool or mechanism that you could consolidate logs from different nodes.

While some vendors might have their own utilities for this purpose, I found this one recently, from MapR which seems a good solution but I did not try that myself, http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Centralized+Logging

I am not sure if the idea of picking up logs and feed into one single map task will work. As you need to know the task and attempt id inside the task Java class file to pick up its own log file after it's completed.